# Rounding error using NSDate functions

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

Consider this code:

```
int64_t seconds = 9223372036854775;
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
NSTimeInterval intervalInSeconds = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

intervalInSeconds contains 9223372036854776, incremented by 1 second.

Is it known behavior and how do I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` takes an argument of type `NSTimeInterval` (which is a typedef for a `double`) and you are passing an `int64_t` which is implicitly being cast to a double when used for the NSTimeInterval argument.

When I tried the simply redefining the variable as a NSTimeInterval:

```
NSTimeInterval seconds = 9223372036854775.0;
```

it resulted in the same value as the result you got:

```
Printing description of seconds: 
(NSTimeInterval) seconds = 9223372036854776
```

so this isn't a problem with NSDate, it's a conversion between `int64_t` and `double`.

Comment: Indeed; if you change `seconds` to an `NSTimeInterval` it is rounded *before* being used to create the `NSDate` object.

Comment: It's not a conversion problem as it also occurs if you assign a floating point literal; it's a floating point rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSTimeInterval seconds = 9223372036854775;
NSLog(@"%f", seconds);
```

prints:

```
9223372036854776.000000
```

So it's got nothing to do with `NSDate`, but is a floating point rounding error (you get the same if you assign the floating point literal `9223372036854775.0`).